# Function call to change properties of an object does not update the view

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have made a class, and it has a function that updates its value. When a button is clicked, this function is called, but the view I made does not update. Here is a very basic version of what I have. The syntax may be incorrect as this is not the exact code but a simplified version demonstrating the general structure.

The Class

```
class TaskCounter: Identifiable
{
    let id:UUID
    var count:Int
    var name:String

    init (id:UUID = UUID(), count:Int = 0, name:String)
    {
        self.id = id
        self.count = count
        self.name = name
    }
    func update() -> Int
    {
        count+=1
    }
}
extension TaskCounter
{
    sampleTasks = 
    [ TaskCounter("A"), 
      TaskCounter("B"),
      TaskCounter("C")
    ]
}
```

The View Structure

```
ContentView
{
    @State tasks[TaskCounter] = TaskCounter.sampleData
    ...
    /// When user selects some option on the bottom bar load smaller view above it
    SmallerView(tasks: $tasks)
    ...
}
```

```
SmallerView
{
    @Binding var:[TaskCounter] tasks
    
    ///List of tasks
    ForEach { task in tasks
        SmallerCardView(task: $task)
    }
}
```

```
SmallerCardView
{
    @Binding task:TaskCounter

    /// On button press, update the internal value of the task object
    Button (action: { task.update()},label {Rectangle()})
}
```

I tried to make the internal subviews use state, since I read that changes to state would force the view to update. Is my understanding of @State and @Binding correct in that @State holds the top level data, and @Binding is for smaller subviews that can manipulate that data?

Comment: You should make `TaskCounter` a struct instead.

Comment: @Sweeper Because I am changing properties in TaskCounter, wouldn't it make sense to use a class so that a copy isn't created each time. Changes to TaskCounter  objects are also expected to be made frequently.

Comment: Unrelated, but at some point if I want to store instances of this object in CoreData, would I have to make additional changes to its type

Comment: @easy-developer structs are value types created on the stack so negligible to copy, no more work than incrementing that int, but Swift has efficient copy on write anyway. Try to use structs in Swift wherever you can!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a "listener" to your **count** variable by using the ObservableObject protocol

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var taskCounter = TaskCounter(name: "Counter")

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Count: \(taskCounter.count)")
                .font(.title)
            
            CountButton(taskCounter: taskCounter)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct CountButton: View {
    @ObservedObject var taskCounter: TaskCounter

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            taskCounter.update()
        }) {
            Text("Increment Count")
                .padding()
                .background(Color.blue)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .cornerRadius(8)
        }
    }
}

class TaskCounter: ObservableObject {
    let id = UUID()
    @Published var count: Int
    var name: String

    init(count: Int = 0, name: String) {
        self.count = count
        self.name = name
    }

    func update() {
        count += 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Per the suggestion of the others, I turned the class into a struct. Now the view, updates, but only on the first button press. If put a breakpoint, I can see that function is called on subsequent button presses, but the view still doesn't update.

Comment: Yeah. that's why you should consider listening to the var so it'll keep updating every time there's a change

Comment: Ahh yes that worked, thank you! For reference: I turned the class type into a struct. Then I made a class that conforms to ObservableObject that holds an array of TaskCounters. Then I passed in the array using State and ObservedObjects to the views, and now the view updates appropriately.